# Вернуть значение функции после выполнения Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, promise

Необходимо создать метод, возвращайщий данные с сервера и кэширующий их. Если происходит повторное обращение к методу, нужно отдавать кэшированные данные.

Хотел бы, чтобы в коде какой-либо разработчик мог не париться и просто вызывать метод.

```
let data = customService.getData(id);
```

Для этого в сервисе `customService` мне нужно делать примерно следующее:

```
let localObj = {};

function getData(id) {
  return localObj.id === id
    ? localObj.data
    : getDataFromServer(id);
}

function getDataFromServer(id) {
  return http.get(url)
    .then(onSuccess);

  function onSuccess(data) {
    localObj.id = id;
    localObj.data = data;

    return data; <---- вот это я хочу вернуть, но возвращается Promise.
}
```

И возникает проблема. При первом обращении к методу

```
let data = customService.getData(id);
```

в `data` находится объект Promise, а не данные.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как научить фунцию возвращать данные из промиса без async/await.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вопрос помечен как дубликат. Видимо, я не правильно донес свою мысль.
Меня интересует, можно ли написать метод в сервисе так, чтобы вызывать его из контроллера можно было без `.then` ?

Понятно, что я могу сделать так:

```
customService.getData(id).then(newData => data = newData);
```

Но хотелось бы все колбэки оставить внутри сервиса, если это возможно.

Comment: Напрямую развернуть результат нельзя. Можно было бы попробовать использовать `async`/`await`, но сама функция при этом тоже будет возвращать `promise`, и если эта функция `controller` то все вообще может сломаться.

Comment: Даже если бы было можно - ни в коем случае не нужно. На время выполнения скрипта страница блокируется, и если скрипт будет ожидать ответа от сервера перед продолжением выполнения, то пользователь в это время не сможет пользоваться зависшим сайтом. А если интернет лаганёт и ответ сервера не придёт, то браузер просто убьёт ваш скрипт как зависший. Промисы и async/await ничего не блокируют - используйте их.

Comment: Можно, если вы не планируете никак пользоваться возвращаемым значением. Если планируете, то вам нужно назначить какой-то код, который его получит (потому что в области видимости вызывающего его нет и не будет), коллбэком или вариациями вроде async/await. Дубликатный вопрос с виду соответствует спрашиваемому.

Comment: нет, такой метод написать нельзя. ты можешь написать метод, который возвращает тебе объект, а при резолве промиса копировать данные в этот объект, но я сомневаюсь, что тебе нужно именно это